# Pyglet, shaders and GLSL layout tag for color attribute

Tags: python, opengl, python-3.x, glsl, pyglet

I'm trying to use pyglet and OpenGL 4 style shaders (ie: not using any matrix operations, using (layout=...) etc...)

I have a basic vertex shader which is:

```
#version 400

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelviewMatrix;

uniform vec2 offset;
varying vec4 vertex_color;

layout(location=0) in vec4 inVert;
layout(location=1) in vec4 inColor;

void main() {
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * ( modelviewMatrix * ( inVert + vec4(offset.x, offset.y, 0, 0) ) );
    vertex_color = gl_Color;
}
```

and a basic fragment shader:

```
#version 400

varying vec4 vertex_color;
out vec4 outColor;

void main(){
    outColor = vertex_color;
}
```

I use

```
a = pyglet.graphics.vertex_list(num*3, ('v4f', vs), ('c4f', color))
```

to define my draw list and use

```
a.draw()
```

within the on_draw(GL_TRIANGLES) function.

As is, this works fine, it properly draws the vertices, offsets them, and they have the right color.

However, I wanted to use the layout(location=1)... line to grab the color instead of using gl_Color.   I would have thought if the calls to glVertexAttribPointer and  glEnableVertexAttribArray  were done for the color attribute in the way I can imagine doing them if I was making the calls to manually, then what I have would work.

I see calls to

```
glVertexAttribPointer(self.index, self.count, self.gl_type,
                          self.normalized, self.stride, 
                          self.offset + pointer)
```

in pyglet's vertexattribute.py, so maybe I am misusing "layout" somehow

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Currently, you're using `glColorPointer` to set up the `gl_Color` value. Can you not change it to be `glVertexAttribPointer`?

Comment: I didn't know that I was using `glColorPointer`. I am just calling pyglet functions and I wasn't clear on how it used the `vertex_list(...)` built-in constructor to create a series of OpenGL commands. I surmise from your answer that if it uses glCOlorPointer internally, then my 'layout' commadn will not work, but if it uses glVertexAttribPointer then it will? Thanks for the guidance.  Here is a link to the pyglet API if it would be helpful. [link](http://pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.graphics-module.html#vertex_list)